# How to create a Script that Archives SPs with variables in table name and DB name?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic

So I know how to do this for all my tables:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(9)
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @month = (SELECT Datename(month, Getdate()))
SET @db = 'MyDatabase'
SET @sql = 'SELECT * INTO ' + @db + '.dbo.MyTable_' + @month
           + ' FROM ' + @db + '.dbo.MyTable'

PRINT @sql

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

But I can't fit several large SPs into @sql variables and even if I could apparently:

*CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' does not allow specifying the database name as a prefix to the object name*

Is there a way to script an SP transfer without its entire text?

If so, how can I get the database name in a variable for `USE [dbname]`

I know with `sqlmcd` mode I can do something like

```
:setvar dbname "MyDatabase" 
USE $(dbname)
```

but I would need to have the dbname as a variable also like

```
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(10)
SET @db = (SELECT Datename(year, Getdate()))
:setvar dbname @db
USE $(dbname)
```

So, the goal is to archive off a bunch of SPs each Month into a database, with new db for each year without having to ever manually change the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and assume you are trying to archive the source code of your stored procedures each month:

```
DECLARE @month VARCHAR(9)
DECLARE @db VARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SET @month = (SELECT Datename(month, Getdate()))
SET @db = 'AdventureWorks'
SET @sql = 'SELECT m.* INTO ' + @db + '.dbo.SPs_' + @month
           + ' FROM ' + @db + '.sys.procedures p '
           + 'INNER JOIN ' + @db + '.sys.sql_modules m ' 
           + 'ON p.object_id = m.object_id'

PRINT @sql

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql
```

The `definition` column in the table will contain the stored procedure code.

Comment: Yes your assumption is correct. However, my goal was to archive them separately as actual stored procedures in another database with the year as part of the dbname. Does the definition column not cut the code off after 8000 characters? These are rather large SPs.

Comment: Don't know why I thought 8000 was the max length apparently its over a billion. This should work as long as I can find a way to format this back into a query window. Since it's all on one line the SQL formatter I use is having trouble due to comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some extra work.  To create a stored procedure in a database, you need:

```
<database>..sp_executesql(<create table statement>)
```

If you know the database, great!  If not, you have to do dynamic sql within dynamic sql.  It ends up being like:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = @databasename+N'..sp_executesql '''+replace(@createsql, '''', '''''')+'''
exec(@sql);
```

I think I got those quotes right.

Comment: Is your answer about how to move tables or stored procs? I'm only asking about the SPs.

Comment: Stored procedures.  In SQL Server, you can't create a stored proc in another database without using dynamic sql.